# Custom SIP VoIP app keeps being closed by Android

Tags: android, api, sip, voip

I've developed a version of the native SIP Demo app provided by Google https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo/

My Simple app registers with the SIP server and when a call invite is received on that SIP account a notification and Toast is displayed with the caller ID. I've not designed the app to run as a service or anything. After launching the activity the app registers with the SIP server and then I simple hit the home button and let the app run in the background, waiting for an incoming call.

The app functions correctly it's just that within ~ 12 - 24 hrs the app seems to have been stopped by the Android OS. I'm not sure if it's related to the native SIP stack or Android's resource manager shutting down the app but I've tried setting everything I can on the handset itself to prevent the app from being stopped like removing any battery saving settings etc.

Are there any tips to keep the app running in the background using the native SIP API?

My is code below:

CallerIDActivity.java -

```
package example.callerid;
//This app has been developed with a target API of 22 so as to avoid having to
//implement runtime permissions on the test handset with a higher API level.

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.sip.SipException;
import android.net.sip.SipManager;
import android.net.sip.SipProfile;
import android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

public class CallerIDactivity extends Activity {

    public SipManager manager = null;
    public SipProfile me = null;
    public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

    public CallerIDactivity (){
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChannel();
    }//end constructor

        //define NotificationChannel method for use in the contructor above
        //IncomingCallReciever will then use this channel to send notification of CID

    public void createNotificationChannel(){
            //Create the Notification but only on API 26+ as the
            //notification class is new and not in the support lib
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                CharSequence name = "CHANNEL_NAME";
                String description = "CID_NOTIFY";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                //Register the channel with the system: you can't change the importance
                //or other notification behaviour after this
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                if(notificationManager !=null) {
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.callerid);

        // Set up the intent filter.  This will be used to trigger an
        // IncomingCallReceiver when someone calls the SIP address used by this
        // application.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.CallerID.INCOMING_CALL");
        callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);

    }//end onCreate

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
        // When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
        // settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
       initializeManager();
   }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        closeLocalProfile();

        if (callReceiver != null) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
            Log.d("CallerID", "UnRegisteringReceiverOnDestroy ");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UnRegisteringReceiverOnDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }//end onDestroy

    public void RegisterBtn(View callerid){
        initializeManager();
        Log.d("CallerIDactivity","RegisterBtn Press");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void initializeManager() {
        if(manager == null) {
            manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        }

        initializeLocalProfile();
    }

    public void initializeLocalProfile() {
        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (me != null) {
            closeLocalProfile();
        }

        try {
            SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("sipaccount", "my.sip.server");
            builder.setPassword("pass");
            me = builder.build();

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("android.CallerID.INCOMING_CALL");
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
            manager.open(me,pi,null);


            // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
            // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

            manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    updateStatus("Ready");
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                                 String errorMessage) {
                    updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                }
            });

        }catch (ParseException pe) {
            updateStatus("Connection Error.");
        } catch (SipException se) {
            updateStatus("Connection error.");
        }


    }

    /**
     * Closes out your local profile, freeing associated objects into memory
     * and unregistering your device from the server.
     */
    public void closeLocalProfile() {
        if (manager == null) {
            Log.d("closeLocalProfile", "manager == null");
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (me != null) {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ClosingProfileURI"+" "+me.getUriString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
         } catch (Exception ee) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ee.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            Log.d("onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the status box at the top of the UI with a messege of your choice.
     * @param status The String to display in the status box.
     */
    public void updateStatus(final String status) {

        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               toast.show();

        }});

/*         Be a good citizen.  Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("allenssip",status);
                TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipLabel);
                labelView.setText(status);
            }
        });
*/
    }//end updateStatus

}//end Class
```

IncomingCallReceiver.java -

```
package example.callerid;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.sip.*;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;


/**
 * Listens for incoming SIP calls, intercepts and hands them off to CallerIDactivity.
 */
 public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public Calendar calendar;
    public SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    public String date;
    public SipManager mSipManager;
    public SipSession mSipSesion;
    public SipProfile peerProfile;
    static private int notifyNum = 1;

    /**
     * Processes the incoming call, answers it, and hands it over to the
     * CallerIDactivity.
     * @param context The context under which the receiver is running.
     * @param intent The intent being received.
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
            try {
                mSipSesion = mSipManager.getSessionFor(intent);
            } catch (SipException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            peerProfile = mSipSesion.getPeerProfile();
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            Log.d("CallerID", "OnReceive");

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setContentTitle("CallerID" + " " + date)
                    .setContentText(peerProfile.getDisplayName())
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            if(notifyNum <= 9) {
                notificationManager.notify(notifyNum++, mBuilder.build());
            }else {notificationManager.notify(notifyNum, mBuilder.build());
                    notifyNum = 1;
            }
            int count = 0;
            while (count <= 10) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, peerProfile.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                count++;
            }//end while

    }//end onReceive

}//end Class
```